# Too much bottom padding applied to google maps infowindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm displaying a Google Maps Infowindow with very little content but there seems to be a lot of padding applied to the bottom of the window.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/m9n2X/2/

The yellow box shows the content I'm displaying in the window. There is no padding or margin applied to the yellow content.

[image: Example]

Javascript

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

var contentString = "<span id='content_string'>I'm a popup window</span>";

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Here's the CSS

```
#map_canvas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

#content_string {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Is there a way to reduce the padding that is applied to the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't padding.  There is a minimum size InfoWindow.  Look at a replacement for the InfoWindow (like [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/)).

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I couldn't see a mention of a minimum size in the API reference. Here's a link to an example page showing the InfoBubble you suggested for future reference: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

Comment: This is not completely correct. This probably applies to this very case, but there IS also a padding (try it with bigger contents), and this doesn't answer to how to reduce it.